# iPhone + save state of application in case of any interruption

Tags: iphone

I have developed a game as iPhone application. Everything is completed and I am ready to upload it on App Store. I need to implement only one feature and that is, when any interruption occurs like a phone call / a sms / a notification, I want to save the current state of game so that whatever user chooses: either to handle that interruption or to cancel that interruption, the game should start again from the same stage.  How might I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the

```
- (void) applicationWillTerminate: (UIApplication *) application
```

message in your `UIApplicationDelegate`. See the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate:).